# Multiple self joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a table named ERRMSG. Errors are in 4 languages (there is a column named LANGU that has values L1, L2, L3, L4). MSGKEY is the app name and MSGNUM is its ID. MSGKEY and MSGNUM together is unique if you select a single language. I'll get them translated so I am creating a translation table in which each translation will be in a single row. My query is getting duplicates :

```
SELECT  X.MSGKEY, X.MSGNUM,
    ISNULL((L1.MESSAGE),'') AS L1TEXT,
    ISNULL((L2.MESSAGE),'') AS L2TEXT,
    ISNULL((L3.MESSAGE),'') AS L3TEXT,
    ISNULL((L4.MESSAGE),'') AS L4TEXT
FROM ERRMSG X
FULL JOIN ERRMSG L1 ON (X.MSGKEY = L1.MSGKEY AND X.MSGNUM = L1.MSGNUM AND L1.LANGU = 'L1')
FULL JOIN ERRMSG L2 ON (X.MSGKEY = L2.MSGKEY AND X.MSGNUM = L2.MSGNUM AND L2.LANGU = 'L2')
FULL JOIN ERRMSG L3 ON (X.MSGKEY = L3.MSGKEY AND X.MSGNUM = L3.MSGNUM AND L3.LANGU = 'L3')
FULL JOIN ERRMSG L4 ON (X.MSGKEY = L4.MSGKEY AND X.MSGNUM = L4.MSGNUM AND L4.LANGU = 'L4')
```

What am I doing wrong ? I am guessing the join type might solve it but can't figure out how.

Comment: Why do you think you are doing something wrong? Did you get unexpected results? Did you get an error?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am getting duplicates

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current results and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: You probably need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: @PeterB LEFT JOIN still returns duplicates

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Please define 'duplicates'. Also: please **[edit]** the question to include sample input, the unwanted output, and the wanted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be solved using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT  MSGKEY, 
        MSGNUM,
        MAX(CASE WHEN LANGU = 'L1' THEN MESSAGE END) AS L1TEXT,
        MAX(CASE WHEN LANGU = 'L2' THEN MESSAGE END) AS L2TEXT,
        MAX(CASE WHEN LANGU = 'L3' THEN MESSAGE END) AS L3TEXT,
        MAX(CASE WHEN LANGU = 'L4' THEN MESSAGE END) AS L4TEXT
FROM ERRMSG 
GROUP BY MSGKEY, MSGNUM
```